# Using client's arguments to create a custom embedded message based off of arguments user left in command (Discord JS)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, discord.js

(Noobish at JS) I'm setting up a Discord Bot command that allows it so the user types out a embedded message. I'd like to use arguments and use it in a command like this

d!cembed ~title~~description~~footer~~color~~thumbnail url~

Code I'm using

```
         async run(message, args)
    {
      var titleargs = message.client
      var descriptionargs = message.client
      var footerargs = message.client
      var urlargs = message.client
      {
        {
            var myInfo = new discord.RichEmbed()
                .setTitle(titleargs)
                .setDescription(descriptionargs)
                .setFooter(footerargs)
                .setColor(0xff0000)
                .setThumbnail(urlargs)


                message.channel.send(myInfo);

        }
    }
    }
}
```

Result Expected : The author of the message / command will create a embedded message

Actual Result : A error appears in terminal

Comment: Perhaps add what the error was?

Comment: (editted code)

(node:61833) DeprecationWarning: Collection#filterArray: use Collection#filter instead
(node:61833) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
    at JSON.stringify (<anonymous>)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I'm sorry if this is not a great answer but, I will do my best.

```
var titleargs = message.client
var descriptionargs = message.client
var footerargs = message.client
var urlargs = message.client
```

message.client would not work in this sense. Client and message are both classes, you would want to use:

```
var titleargs = message.content;
var descriptionargs = message.content;
var footerargs = message.content;
var urlargs = message.content;
```

Content is a property of the message class which allows you to use user input.
https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content

Furthermore,

```
var myInfo = new discord.RichEmbed()
            .setTitle(titleargs)
            .setDescription(descriptionargs)
            .setFooter(footerargs)
            .setColor(0xff0000)
            .setThumbnail(urlargs);


            message.channel.send(myInfo);
```

.setThumbnail(url) will only work with a correctly formatted url.
You can find more on that here, https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/RichEmbed?scrollTo=setThumbnail as well as the other methods for RichEmbed. I hope this helps!